# Dependence on Storyboard and bad practices

Tags: ios

I am a beginner at best when it comes to xcode, iOS, and objective-c. I have been working on a project that has had me looking up information a lot. I have already been learning a lot, but I realized lately that I have forming some bad practices.

I have used Storyboard to lay out the abstract view of the app. The first thing I noticed I was doing dealt with popover views for iPad. I did not know how to dismiss them via button press, so I was creating a new modal segue from the popover button back to the main view.

I realized that this was creating a new view and placing it over my existing view. This would start to chain until the program eventually crashed. Last night I learned the importance of delegates and how they can help me gracefully dismiss the popover view.

Based on the documentation I have read for modal views, it appears that I need to be dismissing those types of views as well.

My question regards to proper practice when building an app. What if I have a ViewController that has 10 buttons, each of which will spawn a popover that is similar yet features slightly different content. Is it OK to create 10 new views in storyboard and drag and drop the UI elements on there? This means that the main view controller is going to have 10 delegates, one for each.

OR would it be best to create one general view, load the content dynamically, and only worry about one delegate in the presenting view controller?

EDIT: As far as the differences between them, they each have a list of labels (questions) and a UISegmentedControl to match the label. This  will allow the user to fill out a survey. There are currently 10 views because I have 10 sets of questions that I feel deserve different views. At the bottom of each view there are 4 buttons. Every view must include these 4 buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "ok" but not practical to have those 10+ delegates.  If these ViewControllers only differ slightly - have you considered creating a "base" view controller and then adding/updating some of the differences programmatically depending on the content?  I think it all depends on what you want to display and how much these differ.  I would definitely not recommend 10+ delegates  all delegating back to the same controller.

Basically, I'm saying yes to your "OR" question.

Comment: I personally do not like having so many views. I would much rather have it done programmatically. I always stress myself over finding the most elegant solution and having these virtual clones didn't feel right.

 Thank you!